# Can't unset some links from woocommerce "My account" nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a project that uses both SenseiLMS and Woocommerce. I can't get rid of some automaticly added nav elements.
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWy8M.png)

The text in english is what I can't unset. What I tried so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'taxguru_remove_my_account_links' );
function taxguru_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){

unset( $menu_links[ 'members-area' ] );
unset( $menu_links[ 'teams' ] );

return $menu_links;
}
```

`

[$menu_link content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvD0.png)
-Those items I want to delete are not there. So i assume they have to be added later by something?

Comment: print this `$menu_links` and add in question what you see.

Comment: @Bhautik I added the image in my question. Those items are not listed there. So I guess that explains why I can't unset them. I am using Woocommerce Membership plugin and Teams. Maybe they are adding those links later?

Answer (score 0):

you can use code like this to unset menu. Also please make sure about slug.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'ak_remove_my_account_links' );
function ak_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){
    
    unset( $menu_links[ 'edit-address' ] ); // Addresses
    
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'dashboard' ] ); // Remove Dashboard
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'payment-methods' ] ); // Remove Payment Methods
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'orders' ] ); // Remove Orders
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'downloads' ] ); // Disable Downloads
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'edit-account' ] ); // Remove Account details tab
    //unset( $menu_links[ 'customer-logout' ] ); // Remove Logout link
    
    return $menu_links;
    
}
```

Comment: This is the exact code I was using. I added a image with what is inside my $menu_links. SInce those elements don't appear there I assume they are somehow added by one of my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **priority**.

```
function taxguru_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){

    unset( $menu_links[ 'members-area' ] );
    unset( $menu_links[ 'teams' ] );

    return $menu_links;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'taxguru_remove_my_account_links', 9999 );
```

Comment: That helped but only a little. It only worked for 'members-area'.